# Java How does the Vector `removeElementAt` function work actually?

Tags: java, vector, collections

I'm a fresh man to Java and now learning the Collections in Java.What makes me confused is that I cannot understand how does the function `removeElementAt` work When I read the source code of `Vector`.

The point that puzzled me is this function remove the element by copying those remaining elements with the function `System.arraycopy`,which just copy the source array to the destination limited in specified length.What if I want to remove those element sit on the middle of array?I assume that it will discard those elements sit behind the spcified element, But it doesn't work like what I thought.

Function `removeElementAt`:

```
public synchronized void removeElementAt(int index) {
        modCount++;
        if (index >= elementCount) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index + " >= " +
                                                     elementCount);
        }
        else if (index < 0) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
        }
        int j = elementCount - index - 1;
        if (j > 0) {
            System.arraycopy(elementData, index + 1, elementData, index, j);
        }
        elementCount--;
        elementData[elementCount] = null; /* to let gc do its work */
    }
```

Followed is my test code:

```
   /**
     * Test if it will discard those element in the back
     */
    public void TestRemoveElementAt(){
        Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            vector.addElement(i);
        }
        // try to remove the number "7"
        vector.removeElementAt(7);
        // expected: 0  1   2   3   4   5   6
        //   actual: 0  1   2   3   4   5   6   8   9
        vector.iterator().forEachRemaining(ele->System.out.print(ele+"\t"));
    }
```

What's wrong with my hypothesis?

Comment: If you are learning from scratch, I suggest avoiding classes that have been obsolete for years, such as Vector. Look at ArrayList instead.

Comment: Thank U, I will adopt your suggestion. But I just want to figure out the reason why my hypothesis is wrong?Maybe I'm a stubborn coder, hha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us see the method signature of `System.arraycopy`

```
public static native void arraycopy(Object src,  int  srcPos,
                                    Object dest, int destPos,
                                    int length);
```

From javadoc of `System.arraycopy`

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the
>         specified position, to the specified position of the destination array.

How it is called

```
System.arraycopy(elementData, index + 1, elementData, index, j);
```

Here, source and destination are same (`elementData`)

We say to start at `index + 1` (*srcPos*) and copy the elements of length `j` to the same array starting at index `index` (*destPos*) where `j = elementCount - index - 1;`

So, `j` would denote the number of elements after the `index` you want to remove. Thus, this shifts all the elements after `index` one position down.

Comment: !! I seem to get the key of it ! just because it's copy operation start at the `index+1` which means the memory space of `index` will be coverd

Comment: Thank u so much, my problem is that I misunderstand the meaning of copy.

Comment: You copy everything starting at `index + 1` writing them (sequentially) starting at `index`

Comment: I do agree with yours!!